# Netbeans deletes resource files in classpath directory on clean and build

Tags: java, netbeans, build, classpath

How can I stop Netbeans from deleting my resource files from when I clean and build the project... At the moment my files are stored in the directory with the .class files.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are placing your resources at wrong place. generally clean and build process in Java project, IDE tends to clean up your directory where `.class` files are stored and recompile the java program to create new class files. You must store any dependency either in the classpath or some other place but not in the directory where .class files are created.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've put them in the src folder, and although it now doesn't delete them, it doesn't read them when I run the .jar file.